# Double border for table

Tags: html, css

I am not very familiar with HTML. Just trying to debug an existing code.

This works fine in IE but not in any other browser like Chrome or Firefox.

```html
<table style="text-align: center;
        width: 98%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 5px; 
    background-color: #9b9bce; 
        border: medium double #9b9bce;
        border-width: 1px;
        bgcolor: #FFFFFF;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
  <tr>
    <td td align="left" style="color : white; font: 30 px; font-weight: bold;">
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does that mean that these are not supported anymore with newer browsers?

I can get this working the same way in all browsers including IE and Chrome.

```html
<table style="text-align: center;
        width: 98%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 5px;
    background-color: #9b9bce; 
    
    border-top: 2px solid #f38e23;
    border-left:2px solid #f38e23;
    border-right:2px solid #f38e23;
    border-bottom:2px solid #f38e23;
        bgcolor: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    ">
  <tr>
    <td td align="left" style="color: white; font: 30 px; font-weight: bold;">
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I cant get the double border thing working that is there in the first one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any double borders before and after the edit.

Comment: place a [div](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) around the table, the div has the 2nd border.

Comment: `bgcolor` isn't a valid property.

Comment: a double style border needs to be at least 3px to show 2 borders of 1px and 1px blank in between: `border:double 3px black;` below 3px how would you split pixels ?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need this thing?
P.S. There is few examples http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-style

```css
.dbl-border {
  border: 3px double blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dbl-border"> </div>
```

Comment: To clarify: The issue is that the OPs original CSS set the `border-width` to `1px` which is too low for a double border.  Eliminating that width results in expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need a border width of at least 3px when setting it as double. (1px for each border plus 1px space between)

Comment: Thanks for that. How do you set "1px for each border plus 1px space between"?

Comment: By setting the border width to 3px with they border style of double, this makes each border 1px plus 1px space between (1+1+1).

Basically you should try to set the border width to values divisible by 3. It will automatically try to apply it evenly to both borders and the space between them.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. I will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick for adding multiple borders to any HTML element is by using `box-shadow` since it can get multiple comma separated shadows.

```html
<table style="text-align: center;
        width: 94%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 5px;
        background-color: #9b9bce;
        border: 2px solid #f38e23;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #0f0, 0px 0px 0px 10px #f00, 0px 0px 0px 15px #00f;">
  <tr>
    <td td align="left" style="color: white; font: 30 px; font-weight: bold;">
      Test
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

With that much CSS, you will not want to set that all inline. I would recommend setting a style block in an external file and link it to the html file, or set the style block in the head of the html.

The double border does work, however, it is every narrow. If you zoom, you can see the 2 border styles.

For a stronger effect, I would review pseudo-elements and utilize ":before option to give you more control. 
I built a sample codepen for you to view a demo. https://codepen.io/ckroll17/pen/LjPGaj

```
<style type="text/css">

    .myBorder{
      border: 3px solid blue;
      background-color: #ea4421;  
      color: #ffffff;
      margin: 8% auto;
      padding: 15px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .myBorder:before{
      background: none;
      border: 4px solid black;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      left: -10px;
      right: -10px;
      bottom: -10px;
    }
</style>
```

```
<table class="myBorder">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
    <td>sed do eiusmod tempor</td>
    <td>Ut enim ad</td>
    <td>adipisci velit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>aspernatur aut odit</td>
    <td>quae ab</td>
    <td>magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem</td>
    <td>consequatur</td>
    <td>laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid</td>
    <td>Quis autem vel eum iure</td>
    <td>reprehenderit qui in ea</td>
    <td>Ut enim ad minima</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the suggestions. I think I can use this:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .bordered {
    width: 98%;
padding: 1px;
    border: 5px double #9b9bce;
  }
  .tablestyle {
background-color: #9b9bce; 
width: 100%; 
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bordered">
<table class="tablestyle">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left; font-size: 23pt; font-weight: bold;">
Box with a border
</td>
<td style="text-align:right; font-weight: bold;">
SOMETEXT
<br>
Time Here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the suggestions. I think I can use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .bordered {
    width: 98%;
padding: 1px;
    border: 5px double #9b9bce;
  }
  .tablestyle {
background-color: #9b9bce; 
width: 100%; 
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bordered">
<table class="tablestyle">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left; font-size: 23pt; font-weight: bold;">
Box with a border
</td>
<td style="text-align:right; font-weight: bold;">
SOMETEXT
<br>
Time Here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```